# Programmatically scrolling on Chrome doesn't work until a manual scroll

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

To make a nice UX for mobile users when my side-drawer menu is open, I'm setting `overflow: hidden` and `height: 100vh` on the App container (everything but the drawer) so that it's unable to scroll it while the drawer is open.

Normally, once you remove the `overflow` and `height` properties, the window will jump back up to the top of the screen. To circumvent that, I'm saving the original scroll position (before the drawer) and then setting it back when the drawer closes with `window.scrollTo(0, pos)`.

What I've noticed is that Chrome cannot programmatically scroll *until you've manually scrolled*. I've tested this by running:

```
if (!drawerIsOpen && drawerIsClosing) {
  let done = false;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (window.scrollY !== this.props.store.app.scrollPosition) {
      console.log('attempting');
      window.scrollTo(0, this.props.store.app.scrollPosition);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

That interval will run forever, but the second you scroll the window manually, Chrome will be able to scroll programmatically and the interval will cease. I've tested this with Safari and Firefox and they don't display this behavior.

Is this something to do with what element has focus? Does Chrome not update it's internal knowledge of scroll position until a user has interacted with the page in some way?

Comment: Can you create a plunker? I haven't had success recreating that [scenario](https://plnkr.co/edit/ke5FScRpxjLHwI2MzNwW?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using `window.scrollBy(0, scrollPosition)`, which seems to not exhibit the same issues as `window.scrollTo()` or `document.body.scrollTop`.